# Is $2^{O(\sqrt{\log (\log^3 n)})} = 2^{O(\sqrt{\log \log n})}$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

As the question states, I am reading somewhere that:

$$2^{O(\sqrt{\log (\log^3 n)})} = 2^{O(\sqrt{\log \log n})}$$

I don't quite see why, though, as $\log^3 n \neq O(\log n)$?

Comment: $\sqrt {\log (\log ^3 n)}  = \sqrt {3\log \log n} $ since $\log(a^b)=b\log a$.

Comment: Amazing! A simple log rule did the trick :D